# HTML- Login system- Prevent direct access of html-page

Tags: html

I have implemented a simple login system in javascript where an user has to input the correct username and password.
If correct, he is redirected to log1.html. There, the user can reach several subpages like log1-sub.html. 
Now, I haven't found a good solution to prevent a user to just type the url in the address bar of the browser to reach the log1.html page.

Can anyone of you give me a short hint please?

Thanks much!

Regards,

enne

Comment: You need a server-side language to do this (PHP, ASP, etc).

Comment: Ok, and do you have a simple example how this can be done with php, please?

Comment: If your server is Apache (which it likely is), `.htaccess` is your simplest method. PHP authentication while not that complicated is a little bit more involved if you want to do it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is a poor solution for this since someone can just turn it off and foil your entire system.

If your server is [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) you can use [`.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#auth) for simple authentication. For [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) see [this resource](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication) Anything more fancy and you will have to handle it with a server-side language as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easily possible without having a "real" web application, using some kind of server-side language (Ruby, Python, PHP, Java, .NET languages...). All these languages have their own sets of frameworks for web development.

Probably the only thing you could do is to configure authentication in your web server (for example Apache supports some 'HTTP BASIC' [authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html)). But this is really very basic authentication mechanism.